# How can I increase my ultrasonic sensor accuracy?

Tags: electrical-engineering, wireless-communication, data, distance-measurement, iot

I am using a long ranged ultrasonic sensor to measure milk height in milk silos. Milk is stirring.

Milk Silos Design: Shows two type of silos both are stirred in different direction

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Engineering SE. What is the current accuracy? What type of Ultrasonic sensor are you using? Where is the sensor located? Please update the question with additional details

Comment: ME007ULSV1 sensor. I am planning to install it on the top of silo. I haven't experimented with it, so no accuracy to show. I have read that due to environmental conditions and motion in milk surface, readings will have error. I have checked the time to distance conversion in my arduino code and also I am using espWiFi module to transmit my data.

Comment: @Ravi please edit your question to add the details instead of putting them in a comment.

Comment: You'll need to utilize some sort of running average on the signal to get a stable reading

Comment: Thanks you all for replaying. The problem is solved. I got silo mechanical design through which i got the speed of agitator(30rpm). Then I checked the area and volume dispersed by the motor and luckily vertical displacement is not large (2cm top). So, I excluded this from my assumptions.